# Explain proof of sum equivalence

Tags: sequences-and-series, binomial-coefficients

I need to prove:

$$\sum_{k=1}^n k{n \choose k} 2^{k-1} = n3^{n-1}$$

I have the answer, but I can't understand how can I get from step 1 to step 2?!

Step 1: $$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k $$

Step 2: $$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=1}^n k{n \choose k} x^{k-1} $$

Step 3: $$x=2$$ gives $$\sum_{k=1}^n k{n \choose k} 2^{k-1} = n3^{n-1}$$

I feel this is simple, but can't figure it out.. I tried substitute $$n = n-1$$ and I get strange results...

Comment: Differentiate $(1+x)^n$ on both the LHS and RHS to get to step 2.

Comment: Are you taking the derivative of both sides?

Comment: You can also simply develop the sum if it feels less like a "trick" to you. Also, check the indexes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have $$(1+x)^n = \sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k $$.

By the uniqueness of the derivative:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}(1+x)^n = \frac{\mathrm{d}}{\mathrm{d}x}\left(\sum_{k=0}^n {n \choose k} x^k\right) $$

Assuming that the derivative of a sum is the sum of the derivatives we have:

$$n(1+x)^{n-1} = \sum_{k=0}^n k{n \choose k} x^{k-1}$$

$x=2$ yields your result.

The proof that "derivative of a sum is the sum of a derivatives" is some analysis-y work that I'm assuming is not required for a simple exercise here. You may want to look it up, however, it is rather interesting.

Comment: Tnx, derivative makes sense. I didn't even try to think that direction...

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach avoids differentiation:
$$\sum_{k=1}^n k \binom{n}{k} 2^{k-1} 
= \sum_{k=1}^n k \frac{n}{k}\binom{n-1}{k-1} 2^{k-1} 
= n \sum_{k=1}^n \binom{n-1}{k-1} 2^{k-1} 
= n (1+2)^{n-1}
= n 3^{n-1}$$