# Prove the following combinatorial identity by differentiating the Binomial Theorem

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, summation, binomial-coefficients, binomial-theorem

$$(2^{n-1} + 1)\sum_{k=0}^{n-2}2^k = \frac{1}{n}\sum_{k=2}^n k \binom{n}{k}3^{k-1} $$

I've tried differentiating the Binomial Theorem and substituting $x = 3, y=1$ and got the RHS. But can't seem to get this to equal the LHS.

I'm stuck. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: Connected : https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1339323

Answer (score 1):

The LHS involves a geometric series:
$$\sum_{k=0}^{n-2} 2^k = \frac{1-2^{n-1}}{1-2} = 2^{n-1}-1$$

Now multiply:
$$(2^{n-1}+1)(2^{n-1}-1) = 4^{n-1}-1$$

Comment: @user2661923 is differentiation required for both sides of the identity?

Comment: Yes, I got it now. Yeah, I differentiated and got the RHS but I couldn't get the LHS.I didn't see the factorization into difference of squares. Thanks

Comment: @RobPratt My bad.  I didn't read the OP's query closely enough.